# ng-repeat: disable dragging/moving of jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-sortable

I've an angular app in which I use jQuery-ui's sortable for sorting/dragging slides.

JSFidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/sriramr/Q5FWt/447/

The template:

```
<div ng-controller="SortableCTRL">
<div id="sortable">
    <div ng-repeat="item in sortableArray">
        {{item}} 
        <a href="" class="dntDrg" ng-click="disp(item)" >
            View
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
function SortableCTRL($scope) {
var sortableEle;

$scope.disp = function(val) {
    console.log(val)
}

$scope.sortableArray = [
    'One', 'Two', 'Three'
];
$scope.dragStart = function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.data('start', ui.item.index());
    ui.item.find('.dntDrg').addClass("hide");
}
$scope.dragEnd = function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.find('.dntDrg').removeClass("hide");
    var start = ui.item.data('start'),
        end = ui.item.index();

    $scope.sortableArray.splice(end, 0, 
        $scope.sortableArray.splice(start, 1)[0]);

    $scope.$apply();
}

sortableEle = $('#sortable').sortable({
    start: $scope.dragStart,
    stop: $scope.dragEnd,
    cancel:".dntDrag"
});
```

}

The view link is inside the sortable element as I want each item in the ng-repeat to have a corresponding view link. Clicking on the View link displays the item's value.

Now I want to disable dragging of the View link, and make it appear as if it is not dragged when the item is sorted. In the fiddle, I've added a class to hide the View link when it is dragged. Is it possible to make it appear static, and yet after the drag ends the view link is correctly associated with its item?

Comment: but why would you want to make the link static? it's more intuitive to drag the link since the link is bound to the item.

Comment: True, but its a business requirement that the link remains static. Also, the item is a supposed to be a slide, which is draggable.